# Debug Unity apps on Xbox One without ID@XBOX?

Tags: unity, xbox

I have developer mode setup on my Xbox One, and can debug Windows Universal apps on it without issue from Visual Studio.

I am playing around with Unity, and would like to be able to debug on my Xbox one in the same way. When I look under Build Settings I see the following:

[image: Unity Build Settings]

Clicking Open Download Page [takes me to this blog post from 2014](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/08/11/unity-for-xbox-one-is-here/).

I have heard from other sources that I should be able to debug Unity games on the Xbox without an ID account, is this the case?

[At this link, it says](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/Developers/id):

> You don't need help from ID@Xbox to begin experimenting with Dev Mode – just download the Dev Mode Activation app on your Xbox One to get started!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the new Xbox One developer mode but is is only made for testing Universal Windows Platform Apps as it limits usable RAM/CPU power/GPU power, so it is pretty limited. But you can do it if you enable dev mode (how to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-activation). Then, Set the Unity Build Target to Windows Store. After that, set the SDK to "Universal 10" and set the UWP Build Type to either "D3D" or "XAML". This creates a Visual Studio Project that you can then deploy with the instructions at the MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/getting-started.

Comment: Nice! Looking through my old emails, it seems as though I do have ID@XBOX (must have registered ages ago and forgotten about it), and I get the monthly email updates, any idea of where to login to download the Unity module?

Comment: first of all you need a dev kit, which you should get from Microsoft, the rest  i don't know. Just read through it all thoroughly. Good Luck!

Comment: Ah right because the dev kit is not the same as developer mode on a retail xbox. Gotcha!

Comment: I also hope your game isn't all the sample scenes, because if it isn't then you should delete those.

Comment: I'm just messing around at this point and trying to get my head around the basics, no plans to publish anything any time soon!

Comment: Then you could probably use dev mode